# Specify JSON and XML Response Formats

Tags: api, rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm using the Caspio API to GET data I have from a table in Caspio - I would like to specify the response format as XML as currently the default is JSON.

Their [documentation](http://howto.caspio.com/integration/web-services-api/rest-api/important-header-parameters/) advises that you must set a parameter name and value within the request header.

Will JavaScript let me define multiple `.setRequestHeader` elements, as when I try this using `request_.setRequestHeader("Accept", application/xml);` - it seems to throw back an error - am I doing anything wrong?

```
function CallWebAPI() {

var request_ = new XMLHttpRequest();  

request_.open("GET", "https://xxxxxx.caspio.com/rest/v1/tables/", true);

request_.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token_);

request_.send();

request_.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request_.readyState == request_.DONE) {
        var response = request_.responseText;


         var parser = new DOMParser();
         var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
         xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("First_Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following below the Authorization header and it worked fine: 
`request_.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");`

I needed to make sure there were quotes in `application/json`.